# Display array results in a table from mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if (isset($_POST[ "submit" ])) {
    $character = sanitize($_POST[ 'character' ]);
    $character = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $character);
    $sql = "select user.ip FROM gamedata, user where gamedata.szName = '$character' and user.Name = gamedata.szAccountName";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) 
        or die('There was an error running the query ['.$db -> error.']');
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $sql2 = "select gamedata.szName FROM gamedata, user where gamedata.szAccountName = user.Name and user.ip = '".$row[ 'ip' ]."' ORDER BY gamedata.szName DESC LIMIT 100";
        $result2 = $db -> query($sql2);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
```

I'm having an issue with getting my results to display correctly and so far the only thing I can do to get any type of results is by using print_r($row); and I'm wanting the results to display in table rows.

The script is having a person enter a character's name and then it searches by that characters username in the user database and finds their IP address. It then looks for all accounts with the same IP address and displays characters that match those usernames.

I'm sorry if this has been asked already I've been searching for hours now and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: Also, your query is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string` [cannot completely safeguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602) against Injection. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please, share the code you're having problems with. It seems the code yo'r sharing in the question is the one that prints out the results. Share the one you said doesn't show any results.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web that show how to product an HTML table from SQL results.

Comment: You don't need two queries, you can use a join to combine them into a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
echo "".$row['szName'] . "<br>";
```

The code works exactly how I needed it to. I don't have to worry about injection as the site for this is restricted by IP address and double authentication.

Comment: there is absolutely no reason to prepend `"".` to the echo line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. This is what I usually use:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Username</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Username</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

You can add a table column/cells for all your fields.

Comment: What I'm wanting it to echo is the szName field only but any time I try to do that I get Notice: Undefined index: szName.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me with a copy of the table